# My <header> background img (nor footer bg) is not behaving as intended, how can I change my HTML/CSS to fix this?

Tags: html, css

Why is my header background is behaving this way and how to change my HTML/CSS in order to ensure the header BG looks the same no matter the screen width, same with the footer. I've tried lots of things and I'm just learning.

I'm including screenshots for specificity.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!-- ------------------------------- Header -------------------------------- -->
        
            <header>
                <div class="container"> 
                    <nav class="header-nav">
                        <div class="logo-container"><h3>travel</h3></div>
                        
                        <ul class="nav-links">
                            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">about</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                        <h1>travel outdoor ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
                </div>     
            </header>
        
<!-- ------------------------------- Header -------------------------------- -->

<!-- ------------------------------- Footer -------------------------------- -->
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
               <div class="footer-wrapper">
                    <nav class="footer-nav">
                        <div class="footer-logo"><h3>travel</h3></div>
    
                        <div class="footer-menus">
                            <ul class="footer-links">
                                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        
                            <ul class="social-links">
                                <li><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">linkedin</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="legal">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita error temporibus quod ipsam suscipit exercitationem possimus autem ad.</>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="thin-line"></div>
                    <p>Travel Agency</p>
               </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

  
<!-- ------------------------------- Footer -------------------------------- -->
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* ------------------------------ Global Styles ----------------------------- */

/* ---------------------------------- Header --------------------------------- */

h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 6.8rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    width: 550px;
}

.header-nav a {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px;
}

.header-nav a:hover {
    background-color: #16D6D1;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-style: none;
    color: #F6F8FA;
}

.header-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo-container {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-link {
    margin-right: 3rem;
}

header {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(./images/image-main.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* ---------------------------------- Header --------------------------------- */

/* --------------------------------- Footer --------------------------------- */
footer {
    background: #F6F8FA;
}

.footer-wrapper {
    height: 350px;
}

.footer-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.footer-menus {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    left: 125px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.footer-menus a {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.footer-links {
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.social-links {
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.legal {
    width: 275px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #777777;
}

.thin-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
}

footer p {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: 777777;
}



/* --------------------------------- Footer --------------------------------- */
```

Screenshots of page:

What I want it to look like:
[page snapshot, intended look as static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68hED.jpg)

What's happening that I don't want:
[...not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkSFA.png)

Any feedback also is welcome, learning and improving! Thank you very much in advance anyone who can take the time to give some advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your CSS. Your HTML is only half of what we need to help. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've added it and feel silly for forgetting it. I will read the document you've linked here, thanks double!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, we added a new `div` right after the header, in `main` element, we gave it a `class` and styled the `width` *100%*, `height` *600px* and `background-image` to cover the `div` which fits on it's place, exactly under the header.

**Open Full Page** it's responsive (The other content of the page below also styled mobile responsive *Basic setup*).

I hope this helps,
Enjoy your time coding =D.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {.container {max-width: 540px;}}
@media (max-width:576px) {.container {padding: 0;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.container {max-width: 760px;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.container {max-width: 960px;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.container {max-width: 1190px;}}

header {
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
}

.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
}

.item {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1a4379;
}

.main-box {
    background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg);
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.other-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.content2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dedede;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.content2-img-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 280px;
}

.content2-img-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.content2-info-box {
    text-align: center;
}

.content2-info-box p {
    margin: 15px 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.content2-info-box h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content2-info-box button {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media(max-width: 576px){
    .other-content {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        height: auto;
    }
    .content1 {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        height: 400px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .content2 {
        width: 94%;
        margin: 10px auto 25px auto;
    }
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar container">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="..." alt="Travel" class="logo-img">
            </div>
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="item">Home</li>
                    <li class="item">About</li>
                    <li class="item">Blog</li>
                    <li class="item">Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-box"></div>
            <div class="other-content">
                <div class="content1"></div>
                <div class="content2">
                    <div class="content2-img-box">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content2-info-box">
                        <p>Lorem</p>
                        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</h1>
                        <button>Read More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue because I want the header image to be responsive and appear underneath the header content in z-space not y-space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`background-size: 100% auto;`

or:

`background-size: cover;`

Comment: I was already using background-size: cover; 100% auto; didn't solve my problem either. I believe it to be an issue with my container? But not sure how to fix or diagnose further. Thank you!

Comment: Try to add your CSS file too. I can' really help you without it :/

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to paste it in, added now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding

```
background-size: cover;
```

If that doesn't work, maybe try to add a background to the container rather than the header.